# Warehouse bug when calling Snowflake REST API

Tags: rest, postman, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am sending a simple REST API call to Snowflake and can't get a simple query to run.
The error indicates a warehouse name needs to be provided, though it's in the request body and I am using Postman templates provided by Snowflake:

```
{
"code": "391920",
"message": "Unable to run the command. You must specify the warehouse to use by either setting the warehouse field in the body of the request or by setting the DEFAULT_NAMESPACE property for the current user.",
"sqlState": "57P03",
"statementHandle": "01b1f84a-3202-3c31-0000-00019b2e60d5"}
```

Just in case the full request(slightly modified account and token):

```
curl --location 'https://ev19561.ap-southeast-2.snowflakecomputing.com/api/v2/statements?requestId=8e80d974-6a9d-4d59-8338-5e2aa4f75f74&async=false' \
--header 'User-Agent: applicationName/applicationVersion' \
--header 'X-Snowflake-Authorization-Token-Type: KEYPAIR_JWT' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJFVjE5NTYwLlNFUkdaQURPUi5TSEEyNTY6Smg3TjJrbnMyaWtJMnZ0eVpnbzljYlU0OW9GbWFGa01sbVZ4RGRLbTdwUT0iLCJzdWIiOiJFVjE5NTYwLlNFUkdaQURPUiIsImlhdCI6MTcwNjQzODU4OCwiZXhwIjoxNzA2NTI0OTg4fQ.IjV2e80fNLJbIkNM6AkYLY6gx_mpmKqfKMf6D9gpW2i6WUTOVwIWAZTMBL-A1jljtLaUjn7YJY0D0RmOOaJZTJvitCLs2jviCSlHGNQx9S-qZbdGYeUQLhTG2Aj0H_dCRwDQziqkypXO64PElrFut2tV1CMUL2y80lzrMdusJqe9pW7xXrcnl_8c_xDkHp41IMtSfA420rNaeeo2tygjFbu0Ly_Iev9RAyzV69-9aLWr_eCFrkKASwrppo6_vjIEjM3zNGe-hHe8SwUTSijpCXVBh8cgYqA0xthwB-BlsRh8yankSI6n2oBZfPjVYbpBVqoAnijNbPcw8sChYYg' \
--data '{
    "statement": "select top 100 * from DB1.SCH1.customer",
    "timeout": "1000",
    "database": "DB1",
    "schema": "SCH1",
    "warehouse": "WH",
    "role": "TEST_ROLE",
    "bindings": {},
    "parameters": {}
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue apparently was - I used hardcoded UUID, so was getting result of the first statement I ran and any new call would not be processed.